# trying to connect to SQL using Get-Credential in Winpe

Tags: sql, powershell, authentication, winpe

Does anyone know how to pass Get-Credentials to a SQL login using powershell?

I have tried many different ways but no success.

This needs to run in winpe - i can get the credentials using Get-Credential but i need to use those to connect to SQL DB - i keep getting.

Login failed for 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN' The below code works fine in Windows - I am logged on as the user though so it must not be passing the credentials. if i remove the trusted_connection=true; i get the failed login and this is the best test for WINPE as no one is logged on. Is there a way to pass those Get-Credentials to SQL? 
Either that or the same code does not work in WINPE - not sure why though?

```
$Cred = Get-Credential

Function SQL_CONNECT ($Query){

    $ConnectionString = "server=VM855;database=LDMS2016;user   id=$Cred.Username;password=$Cred.Password;trusted_connection=true;"
    $SqlConnection = New-Object  System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection($ConnectionString)
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $a = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    $DataSet.Tables[0]
}

$Owners = SQL_CONNECT "Select Task_Name, Task_owner, first_action_query_date from PROV_HISTORY_TASK" | Select-Object Task_Owner, first_action_query_date

$Owners
```

Comment: `$cred.password` is a secure string, not the actual password to use. Use `$cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password` to get to plain text password.

Comment: this is not working in winpe? unless i am putting it in wrong place...

Comment: `$cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password` only works if you are connected to an Active Directory domain. It is complicated to get Active Directory authentication in WinPE because the WinPE is not connected to the domain. i.e. in this case, Windows Authentication is really hard to get working and will require lots more investigation. Use SQL Authentication, as it doesn't depend on Active Directory for authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL connections use either:

- Windows Authentication ("Trusted_Connection=True")

or

- SQL Authentication ("User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;")

You cannot have both "Trusted_Connection" and "User ID/Password", you have to pick one.

In order to use Windows Authentication, the PowerShell process must be running as the user that has access to the database. i.e. you have to launch the PowerShell process as impersonating that user, and run your code.

Rough example will look something like this:

```
# Get the other user's credentials
$credential = Get-Credential

# Execute a scriptblock as another user
$commands = @'
#....code....    

$ConnectionString = "server=VM855;database=LDMS2016;trusted_connection=true;"

#.....etc....
'@

Start-Process -FilePath Powershell.exe -LoadUserProfile -Credential $credential -ArgumentList '-Command', $commands
```

Or, the easier method is to just use SQL authentication, and hard code the username/password.

```
 $ConnectionString = "server=VM855;database=LDMS2016;user id=Username;password=Password;"
```

Or at the very least you will have to use `Read-Host` to read in the username and password because `$Cred.Password` returns `System.Security.SecureString` and not the password in plain text.

For ex.

```
 $Username = Read-Host "User:"
 $Password = Read-Host "Password:"

 $ConnectionString = "server=VM855;database=LDMS2016;user id=$Username;password=$Password;"
```

Comment: Thanks going to try and launch powershell as the user..  see if that will work - i need a GUI to login with not read-host  thks

Comment: Use plain old read host:
`$Username = Read-Host "User:"`
`$Password = Read-Host "Password:"` 
and use SQL authentication -not- Windows Authentication (i.e. Trusted connection). See my last example

Comment: i just tried read-host any way and it still says NT Authority Anonymous is the one trying to connect... testing powershell as run by credentials

Comment: So no joy :( -Credential is not supported for the cmdlet 'Start-Process' on this edition of windows.....

Comment: Do you have SQL authentication turned on on your Database? you have to likely create a new SQL user with rights onto your database. You will not be able to use Windows authentication,

Comment: yes all this works in windows 10 - its just winpe - just tested the read-host and windows was fine but winpe is not - there must be a way to connect to SQL in winpe hopefully using get-credential..... the user i am testing with is me.. and it has read access to SQL

Comment: You can't use `Get-Credential` in the way I think you are thinking you can use it. `Get-Credential` only *stores* your username and password. -Nothing else-. It does not *Authenticate* with Active Directory. (you can prove this by typing in your username, and giving a bad password). Hence why you can't just use it to access the database using a trusted_connection. Whenever you provide a username/password, you use SQL authentication (a completely different method of authentication) which needs you to go to your database, and add in a new login that uses SQL authentication, not Windows auth.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for how to add a SQL authentication user

Comment: I ended up using a SQL login with only read access to one table - this allowed me to hardcode the security - thank you for your help.